# jQuery infinite scroll double load

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using infinity load with jquery.window.scroll function with these codes.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        var page = $('#lastPostsLoader').attr('page')*1;
        $('#lastPostsLoader').attr('page', page + 1);
        DataLoadFunction(page);
    }
});
```

But these codes requesting double time and sometimes false pages when scroll to bottom. Like this;

Scroll bottom---> loading page 1 and loading page 2--->scroll bottom--->loading page 3 and loading page 2--->scroll bottom--->loading page 4 an loading page 5 ........

So where am i wrong? Thanks...

Comment: You'd probably want to set a flag to true when the page number changes, and then set this to false in `DataLoadFunction` once it is finished. Otherwise if you scroll to the bottom, and then scroll again, it will call that function twice (and if you scroll more, it will call that function more times). I've run into a similar issue before and using a flag worked for me. You would then check if `!loading`, assuming your flag is called `loading`, in your if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should prevent dataload till next data arrive. set variable isLoadingData  as true while  data is being loaded from server.

```
var isLoadingData;
 $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  (($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && !isLoadingData ){
              isLoadingData = true; 
            var page = $('#lastPostsLoader').attr('page')*1;
            $('#lastPostsLoader').attr('page', page + 1);
            DataLoadFunction(page, function(){ //  callback get called after data load
                        isLoadingData  = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I suggest you to try $(window).unbind('scroll').scroll. unbind scroll before binding. It may possible that scroll got attached twice with window.

Comment: Ok. I revised ajax load target divs and i used your solve. So really running good... Thanks..

Comment: Try to use setInterval instead of onscroll.